# Backing Windows Server 2008 Foundation

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

I'm about to buy a server from Dell. A very basic 1st generation server that will act as a file server. I want to have this thing back up onto an external hard drive nightly. What's an inexpensive solution to doing this? When configuring the options for the computer at dell, the backup options cost as much as the server!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Server Backup is included in Windows Server 2008 Foundation Edition.

Comment: I heard it doesn't have an automatic nightly backup option. Is this true?

Comment: Nope, not true. You can schedule regularly occurring backups with it.

Answer (score 1):

I used [this one](http://www.fbackup.com/) for one of my clients.

Comment: +1. I've used that as well, but suggested Windows Server Backup since it's included.

Comment: well, i would have voted +1 but I need 15 rep to do so ;-). I guess points dont transfer from other stacks